# session handling in struts 2

Tags: session, struts2

I am stuck with a session handling problem for past few days.

I am working on an application where an user logs into his account and can register there details or change them. How to manage sessions in this case. I mean how can i access the attribute of a session in different action classes?

Also when i click on log out and after that i press the back button given in the browser it goes back to the previous page and user can change their details which should not happen. Please help !!

Comment: Also please tell how to manage concurrent users here in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The back button "issue" is because you have not disabled page caching.

Sessions data is available in actions via the `SessionAware` interface.

Sessions are per-user (more or less, actually per-conversation, and how that's implemented varies somewhat across browser versions), not sure what you mean regarding concurrent users.